# What is this "KotlinRulezzz" package all about?

Tags: android, eclipse, package, kotlin

`Eclipse` suggests a package named *"KotlinRulezzz"*.

What is this package all about? Is this some kind of Easter egg?

[image: KotlinRulezz]

Comment: If you have the choice, use IntelliJ for Kotlin development!

Comment: What is package "puni" about?

Comment: @donfuxx it´s just the main package of this project ... take a look on the left upper site of the screenshot

Comment: Ah ok.. well, maybe eclipse is autosuggesting something. just try to import the package and see what classes are in it :-)